# How to read <p> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I'm trying to make Random colour generator, but I found one problem.
To make this, I have to read text in paragraph with JS. I don't want to use any libraries . Just HTML and JS.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Literally the first google result of your question title will answer this for you.

Comment: You should provide the code, I think what you are trying to ask is just get the data from an html element.  
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].textContent;

Comment: Hey people i encourage all of you to not to vote down the [basic[ questions, there are people out there just learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use id to get the element you want to style.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p  id="myp">Click the button to change the style of the p element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var color1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var color2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var color3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    
    document.getElementById("myp").style.color = "rgb("+color1+","+color2+","+color3+")";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure about your needs but i guess maybe u can

```js
var innerText = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
```

this is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp) if you need more info about it.

If you feel like you can use some classes it's better to use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find all `p` tags in a document and extract the text?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(paragraph => {
  console.log(paragraph.textContent);
})
```

This will find all `p` tags in the document, and for each paragraph, the text will be extracted, allowing nested tags, such as `b`, `i` to handled just like the rest of the text.

If you want to get all of the HTML, you could do

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(paragraph => {
  console.log(paragraph.innerHTML);
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML